# Reading a single line by number from .txt file

Tags: objective-c, file

I'm making a "get a new word every day" program and it picks a word at random from a [large text file](http://sargeant45.github.io/word-a-day/dictionary.txt).

It works like this in C#:

```c#
int randomword = word.Next(1, 58110); // Pick a random valid line (last is 58110)
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(dictionarypath); // Read all lines into an array
string word = lines[randomword]; // take the chosen line from the array
```

So, basically, it creates an array and chooses a line from it randomly.
*I want to do that in Objective-C.*

Are there ways to do this?
More importantly, **are there fast ways to do this?**

Comment: What is your question? And in what language? And how far did you get? Show some of that. BTW: How is your age and lack of experience relevant to posing an acceptable question?

Comment: There is no way in any common language using the standard I/O facilities to read a specific line of a file by line number.  One must somehow read through the entire file and count lines.

Comment: @Deduplicator I fixed the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: So, you want objective-c? Removed c for you.

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah, I do. It doesn't really matter, right? If it works in C, it works in Objective-C, right?

Comment: Maybe it would work in objective C if it works in C, no idea about that. It would **still not be a C question**. Anyway, now it's answerable, so voted to re-open.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, I'm really new here. So pardon my nonsensical-ness.

Comment: @Deduplicator when will my question reopen?

Comment: At the moment, there are three of five needed re-open votes. And I don't know whether it will be re-opened. Or when.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below sample code:-

```
NSString* filePath = @""// your file path...
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"txt"];

// Now for reading everything from text
NSString* fileContents =
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Now, separate by new line
NSArray* allLinedStrings =
[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
 [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

//Now Iterating and printing
for (NSString *ln in allLinedStrings)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",ln);
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the line number?

Comment: You can put according to your requirement